# Seeking contrived example code: continuations!

Tags: scheme, continuations, coroutine

So I believe I understand continuations now, at least on some level, thanks to the [community scheme wiki](http://community.schemewiki.org/?call-with-current-continuation) and [Learn Scheme in Fixnum Days](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/dorai/t-y-scheme/t-y-scheme-Z-H-15.html#node_chap_13).

But I'd like more practice -- that is, more example code I can work through in my head (preferably contrived, so there's not extraneous stuff to distract from the concept).

**Specifically**, I'd like to work through more problems with continuations that resume and/or coroutines, as opposed to just using them to exit a loop or whatever (which is fairly straightforward).

Anyway, if you know of good tutorials besides the ones I linked above, or if you'd care to post something you've written that would be a good exercise, I'd be very appreciative!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, continuations can be pretty mind-bending. Here's a good puzzle I found a while back - try to figure out what's printed and why:

```
(define (mondo-bizarro)
  (let ((k (call/cc (lambda (c) c)))) ; A
    (write 1)
    (call/cc (lambda (c) (k c))) ; B 
    (write 2)
    (call/cc (lambda (c) (k c))) ; C
    (write 3)))

(mondo-bizarro)
```

---

Explanation of how this works (contains spoilers!):

1. The first `call/cc` stores returns it's own continuation and stores it in `k`.
2. The number `1` is written to the screen.
3. The current continuation, which is to continue at point B, is returned to k, which returns to A
4. This time, k is now bound to the continuation we got at B
5. The number `1` is written again to the screen
6. The current continuation, which is to continue at point B, is returned to k, which is another (but different) continuation to another point B
7. **Once we're back in the original continuation, it's important to note that here k is still bound to A**
8. The number `2` is written to the screen
9. The current continuation, which is to continue at point C, is returned to k, which returns to A
10. This time, k is now bound to the continuation we got at C
11. The number `1` is written again to the screen
12. The current continuation, which is to continue at point B, is returned to k, which returns to C
13. The number `3` is written to the screen
14. [And you're done](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_p52QJi-Ydo#t=0m53s)

Therefore, the correct output is `11213`. The most common sticking point I've put in bold text - it's important to note that when you use continuations to 'reset' the value of k that it doesn't affect the value of k back in the original continuation. Once you know that it becomes easier to understand.

Comment: Hmm, yes, this is destroying my brain. csi says the result is 11213, but I can only understand the '112'... I must be missing something!

Comment: Thank you, the bolded point was exactly where I was confused. Let me try this again... :)

Comment: Thanks again. This exercise was very helpful. I'm not a smart man, so I need as much of this as I can get!

Comment: Don't berate yourself - it took a while for me to get it too. The stumbling block isn't even one caused by continuations but by the way variables are bound in Scheme.

Answer (score 4):

Brown University's programming languages course has a [problem set on continuations](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/csci1730/2008/Assignments/08-continuations.html) publicly available.